# Calculate coordinates of a GPS point according to an average speed and an arrival time

Tags: algorithm, gps

I have to following equation: I have a origin GPS point (A) and a destination GPS point (B). I know that my object (X) is traveling at an average speed (S) and that is it supposed to arrive at B at an expected time (T).

I'd like to have two functions:

- one to estimate the GPS location of my object according to all the parameters above
- one estimate a % of distance traveled on the vector between A and B (for exemple: X is just in between A and B the % should be 50%).

As it's based on GPS system and the context is a geographical one, that would be nice if the function would take into account the shape of Earth.

Would be great if written in Golang but it can be any language, I need the logic more than the code itself, I can make the translation later.

I tried some algorithm with copilot but it can up with negative values, which should not be possible.

Comment: Shape of the Earth? Just use it as sphere (it is a very good approximation). To calculate the shorter path may be a little more tricky (especially for long ways, and *special cases* (which you should never ask copilot: use it to speed up what you know, not for the rest). Else look Wikipedia (but we are into numerics, so calculations should be made carefully (and in a controlled order) not to lose precision). libgeographics (or some similar name) may be useful

Comment: The logic is going to be rather complicated, so I'd refrain from implementing this myself. Quick search for go returned [go-geo-wgs84](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/lvdlvd/go-geo-wgs84) which looks sufficient for your task but I'm sure there are other packages